# Divide and assign a variable on the K8S pod level

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-helm

I have a K8S cluster; In one deployment inside this cluster has a variable in the ConfigMap. This variable contains a list of objects. I want to divide the list of objects and assign the subset to the number of pods in the deployment. The goal is to make it dynamic.

#### Example

I will give an example to make clear.
Let's assume the variable as 9 objects and the deployment has 3 pods. I want to divide the list (9 objects/ 3 pods = 3 objects/pod). So Pod1 has objects 1,2,3; Pod2 has objects 4,5,6; Pod3 has objects 7,8,9.

[image]

Note: I'm using Terraform to manage the resources and manage the variables.

Comment: You need 3 different deployments/statefulset for the 3 pods for sure. How are you creating those pods?

Comment: I'm creating them via Terraform module. I set the `replicas` number in the deployment.

Comment: My question is: what do you do with terraform exactly? What resource do you create? A pod directly or a `deployment`?

Comment: I'm creating a **Deployment** via Terraform.

Comment: Ok, so you will need to create 3 deployments then, because your podspec is different between the 3 pods and that's not achievable with a single deployment

Comment: What are the "objects"; do you need to statically assign them to pods?  Does it make sense for your application to put the objects into a job queue like RabbitMQ, and then let replicas pull items off the queue as they become available?